# async api call not returning in swift widget

Tags: ios, swift, api, widget

Im trying to get my weather app to display the weather on a widget. I have no problems with fetching the data in my app itself however for some reason when calling it from the widget, its not getting into the timeline. Here is my func to fetch the weather.

```
func getCurrentWeather(latitude : CLLocationDegrees, longitude : CLLocationDegrees)  async throws -> ResponseBody
{
    let forReal = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&appid=&units=metric"
    guard let url = URL(string: forReal) else {fatalError("MISSING URL")}

    let urlrequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlrequest)
    
    guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { fatalError("ERROR FETCHING CURRENT WEATHER")}
    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseBody.self, from: data)
    print(decodedData)
    return decodedData
}
```

and here is my getTimeline

```
@State var weather: ResponseBody?
var weatherManager = WeatherManager()

func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
    widgetLocationManager.fetchLocation(handler: { location in
            print(location) })
    
    if let location = widgetLocationManager.locationManager?.location
    {
        Task
        {
            do {
            weather =  try await weatherManager.getCurrentWeather(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            } catch {  print("ERROR GETTING WEATHER:", error)  }
        }
        if let weather = weather
        {
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: Date(), feelslike: weather.main.feelsLike, description: weather.weather[0].description))
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: Date())!, feelslike: weather.main.feelsLike, description: weather.weather[0].description))
        } else
        {
            print("no weather")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("No location")
    }
    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```

I am getting a location and I know my api call is working however I think the problem is that it is coming through after I've already checked if its been fetched. At least thats the order that its getting printed in the console. I thought Task{} was async and so would execute that function and wait until completion before moving on? My console returns

```
No location
no weather
```

followed by 4 location fetches and then a weather api fetch however its not managing to get into my timeline for some reason. Probably missing something super obvious but appreciate the help all the same :)

Answer (score 1):

We are facing a similar issue, but only on iOS 14 devices. The story:
We have API based on Combine and it worked well for widget and intent extensions. Later we switched to async/await, and were very happy because a lot of API implementations were simplified, but... we tested mostly the main app, and after a month or so we realised that our widgets stopped working on iOS 14, showing a placeholder instead of the real content. After debugging it come that the execution crashes when we debugging the flow on completion handlers or methods that are used one by one, meaning that iOS destroyed the related objects due to some reason (obviously because timeline generation should be as quick as possible, and system decided that it's time to complete). Switching back to Combine (manually for the used methods only) shown that it works fine after the rollback.

Hence, the conclusion is that async/await methods generate tasks differently than GCD, and in iOS14 it results in some huge task hierarchy that is treated incorrectly in the app extensions (just a guess). Seems there is an issue in iOS 14. End of the story.

Try to use Combine or at least GCD directly for asynchronous tasks. And let me know if that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look up how concurrent coding with `completionHandlers` and how `Task` work.

E.g.:

```
widgetLocationManager.fetchLocation(handler: { location in
        print(location) 
    })
    

// This line will run before `fetchLocation(...` has run, so you need to move it inside
// the completion closure of `fetchLocation`
if let location = widgetLocationManager.locationManager?.location
{
```

The same at this point:

```
Task{
    do {
    weather =  try await weatherManager.getCurrentWeather(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    } catch {  print("ERROR GETTING WEATHER:", error)  }
}
// the code inside task may run synchronous in its own thread
// but this line of code will execute concurrently at the same time
// so weather will be nil the first time
if let weather = weather
{
```

Here I fixed these errors:

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
    
    widgetLocationManager.fetchLocation{ location in
        print(location)
        
        guard let location = location else{
            print("No location")
            return
        }
        
        Task
        {
            do {
                weather =  try await weatherManager.getCurrentWeather(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            } catch {  print("ERROR GETTING WEATHER:", error)  }
            
            guard let weather = weather else{
                print("no weather")
                return
            }
            
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: Date(), feelslike: weather.main.feelsLike, description: weather.weather[0].description))
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: Date())!, feelslike: weather.main.feelsLike, description: weather.weather[0].description))
            
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}
```

### But

I cannot guarantee this will work as intended. You would need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can debug and check. It will at least point you in the right direction how this should be structured.

[WWDC asyn/await](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/)

[Swift docs closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I followed your advice but weather was still returning nil, so I ended up putting the entries.append and the do statement

Comment: @MattPidden as I allready told you you would need to provide more context here if you need more help. Please read [mre] and [ask]. If this helped you solve your problem you can mark this as the accepted answer (green checkmark).